# How does c# convert long to a single byte

Tags: python, c#, types, byte

Im trying to rewrite a c# function to python. Now ive come to a line which looks like this:

```
timeArray[i - 1] = (byte)timestamp;
```

Obviously it just parses the var "timestamp", which is a long of length 10 to a byte. But how does this work, and how can i reproduce it in python?
for reference, here the full version of the c# code:

```
var timestamp = long.Parse("1647079653");
var timeArray = new byte[8];
timestamp /= 30L;
for (var i = 8; i > 0; i--)
{
    timeArray[i - 1] = (byte)timestamp;
    timestamp >>= 8;
}
```

this returns an array of [0,0,0,0,3,69,191,127]

when i do it in python (using the built in bytes-function) i get insane numbers for each index of the array, altough the inital values of the timestamp are correct (like 6-7 digits)
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Okay i figured it out. It just takes the last 8 bits of the corresponding binary and this is then the byte. The working python code:

```
    for i in range(8,0,-1):
        num = str(bin(int(timestamp)))
        timeArray[i-1] = int(num[len(num)-8:],2)
        timestamp = int(timestamp)
        timestamp >>= 8
```